# How to import a single excel file/sheet with various Models (and sub-data/models) in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, import, import-from-excel, maatwebsite-excel

As per the title, I have a single excel file full of data (parent/child) in each row. The Laravel Excel site shows how to import, assuming a single model per row - but how does one import the child data?
https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/3.1/imports/

eg 'pseudo' schema:

```
    Schema::create('students', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->string('student_code',16);
        $table->string('student_name',64);
        $table->string('student_surname',64);
    });
    Schema::create('student_courses', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->integer('student_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->string('course', 32);
        $table->date('start_date');
        $table->date('end_date');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
    Schema::create('student_contacts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->integer('student_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->string('contact_name', 32);
        $table->string('contact_number', 32);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Eg File: students.xlsx

```
Student Code | Student Name | Student Surname | Course  | Course Start Date | Course End Date | Contact Person | Contact Numbers
ABC1         | Arnold       | Clarp           | C++     | 2019-01-01        | 2019-12-01      | Boogle         | 555-111-222
DEF2         | Delta        | Flork           | English | 2019-01-02        | 2019-12-02      | Google         | 555-111-333
GHI3         | Goblin       | Clark           | Science | 2019-01-03        | 2019-12-03      | Foogle         | 555-111-444
```

Assuming my import code:

```
class StudentsImport implements ToModel, WithStartRow
{
/**
* @param array $row
*
* @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
*/
public function model(array $row)
{
    return new Student([
        'student_code'                  => $row[1],
        'student_name'              => $row[2],
        'student_surname'               => $row[3],
    ]);
}

/**
* @return int
*/
public function startRow(): int
{
    return 2;
}
}
```

Where would I actually go about plugging in the import of the "child" course/contact data?
I'm guessing that instead of 'returning a new student' - I would actually first assign it to a variable, then import it then? Is this the correct way?
eg:

```
public function model(array $row)
{
    $student = new Student([
        'student_code'=> $row[1],
        'student_name'=> $row[2],
        'student_surname'=> $row[3],
    ])
    $student->courses()->create([
        'course'=>$row[4],
        'start_date'=>$row[5],
        'end_date'=>$row[6]
    ]);
    $student->contacts()->create([
        'contact_name'=>$row[7],
        'contact_number'=>$row[8]
    ]);
    return $student;
}
```

//actual code as it stands, no longer 'pseudo':

```
    $student = new Student([
        'bursary_provider_id' => 1,
        'bursary_provider_reference' => 'xxx',
        'student_name' => $row[1],
        'student_initials' => $row[3],
        'student_surname' => $row[2],
        'passport_number' => $row[7],
        'passport_expiration' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::excelToDateTimeObject($row[9]),
        'country_id' => 7,
        'id_number' => $row[6],
        'status' => $status,
        'notes' => $row[5]
    ]);

    if (isset($row[10])) {
        $student->visas()->create([
            'country_id' => 201,
            'visa_reference_number' => $row[10],
            'visa_expiration_date' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::excelToDateTimeObject($row[11])
        ]);
```

**Error** (its not passing across the parent id)

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'student_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `student_visas` (`country_id`, `visa_reference_number`, `visa_expiration_date`, `student_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (201, ABCHFV4, 2019-12-31 00:00:00, , 2019-01-11 08:03:06, 2019-01-11 08:03:06))

Comment: That should work. Are you facing any trouble?

Comment: I'm a Laravel noob and I am uncertain its the correct way to do it so havent gone through the process - want to make sure I am doing it correctly...

Comment: Check my edit ^ I can confirm it doesnt actually work - the parent ID isnt getting carried through...

Comment: You have a column `student_id` in `student_visas` that cannot be null. Can we see your relationship definitions between `Student` and `StudentVisa`? :)

Comment: My understanding is that the parent ID is null because the student hasnt actually been inserted into the database at this stage. Laravel Excel appears to only insert at the very end. Doesnt have to do with my relationships - though for clarity, I do have a foreign key setup.

Answer (score 1):

You get the error because the student is not yet written to de database, so no id has been assigned to the new student instance. If you use collections the data is immediately written to the database. In the model function you can use

```
$student=Student::Create(['bursary_provider_id' => 1,
    'bursary_provider_reference' => 'xxx',
    'student_name' => $row[1],
    'student_initials' => $row[3],
    'student_surname' => $row[2],
    'passport_number' => $row[7],
    'passport_expiration' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::excelToDateTimeObject($row[9]),
    'country_id' => 7,
    'id_number' => $row[6],
    'status' => $status,
    'notes' => $row[5]]);
```

This will write the student to the database and generate the neccessary id. I am not sure how this affects performance though.

Answer (score 0):

The answer, (and do not ask me why, because documentation is so poor at this stage) is to use collections.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;
```

and instead of ToModel:

```
public function collection(Collection $rows)
```

and it doesnt 'return' anything. Other than these changes, using the exact same code in OP works as intended.